# Output of Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Can anyone please let me know how can i execute the below stored procedure in oracle:-

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE spValidateDBA(
    UserId IN VARCHAR2,
    UserPassword IN VARCHAR2,
  UserRole OUT STRING_ARRAY)
  AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select GRANTED_ROLE into UserRole from DBA_USERS DU,DBA_ROLE_PRIVS DRP where DU.USERNAME=UserId and
    DU.PASSWORD=UserPassword AND DU.USERNAME=DRP.GRANTEE';
    END spValidateDBA;
```

STRING_ARRAY is an array type of strings as declared in this statement:-
CREATE TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);

Please let me know for any questions.

Comment: Column `PASSWORD` in table `DBA_USERS` contains only a password hash, not the clear password.

Comment: is there a way then to validate the db password against a particular user for user validation?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. User is validated when he logon to the database where he has to enter his personal password.

Comment: Maybe a shorter way of getting desired information is this function: [DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED(<rolename>)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sessio.htm#i1010291). It also covers if a role is granted to another role.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write anonimous pl/sql block:

```
DECLARE
<declare variables>
BEGIN
<set values to the variables>
spValidateDBA(<your variables>);
END;
/
```

If you are running in SQL*Plus or something similar, you need that extra / at the end.
If you are running through some API, you may not need it.